# I have installed bourbon/neat not still getting errors

Tags: npm, bower, bourbon, neat

I have install bourbon and neat in the following way:

```
sudo gem install bourbon
sudo gem install neat

bower install bourbon
bower install nean
```

I have included them with:

```
@import bourbon
@import neat
```

I tried but removed:

```
@import bourbon/bourbon
@import neat/neat
```

Comment: Here is the error I am getting
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/2351/Screen_Shot_2015-03-24_at_10.56.43_AM.png

Answer (score 0):

Running `bower install bourbon` should have created a directory called `bower_components` and placed the bourbon files inside of it.

Your import needs to reflect that, for example you could write:

```
@import 'bower_components/bourbon/app/assets/stylesheets/bourbon';
```

Now you can use bourbon mixins in your sass file.